# notify client using some form of Node.js based job queue after upload file , read , insert operations

Tags: node.js, socket.io, rabbitmq, queue, job-queue

is there a way by which i can update client side after below series of activities

```
   1 upload file
   2. read file
   3. bulk insert 
   4. update client that job is completed.
```

I am able to perform

```
1.upload file through through busboy. 
2.read file node sync/async node.js file read.
3.bulk insert sequelize bulk insert.(data read through bluebird mapSeries).
4.(missing piece) since i insert around 200k records in single shot. it might take some time
```

hence i was thinking put in a job queue and after completion notify client through socket.io or rabbitMQ !
Any suggestions, pointers on how to achieve 4th pointer !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your client is some form of Web Client, you have the option to use push and/or long polling technologies to send a message back to the client.

Two Popular libraries to do so are:
https://socket.io/
http://www.lightstreamer.com/

Both have extensive tutorials - if you could be more specific about what you need I can help tailor this answer to you.